# advantages of sp = subprocess.Popen() --> sp.communicate() vs subprocess.call()

Tags: python, scripting, system-administration

I wrote a func that I use constantly about 4 months ago and I'm having trouble remembering why I split things off like this:

```
def call_sp(command, **arg_list):
    #run that beast
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, **arg_list)
    p.communicate()
```

I read the doc on subprocess and see call() essentially does the same thing. Without remembering what happened that day, do any python sysadmins know a meaningful difference in use besides the above func and subprocess.call(["mycommand"])? I see my func doesn't return any exit status, is checking if the command worked the only difference/advantage for call()? Here is what I see today

```
In [4]: subprocess.call(['echo $HOME'], shell=True)
/home/cchilders
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: %paste
def call_sp(command, **arg_list):
    #run that beast
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, **arg_list)
    p.communicate()

## -- End pasted text --


In [6]: call_sp('echo $HOME')
/home/cchilders
```

thanks

Comment: `subprocess.call` really is just a convenience for situations like this. Perhaps you planned on doing something else with `p` (the `Popen` instance), but never did? (In fact, you could define `call_cp = subprocess.call`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.call(..)` is essentially `Popen(..).wait()` that is different from `Popen(..).communicate()` if you redirect any of standard streams of the child process e.g., `stdout=PIPE` or if you need the exit status.

[`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is a convenience function that is built on top of the interface provided by `Popen()`. If `call()` works in your case; use it. If it doesn't work; consider other convenience functions such as `subprocess.check_output()` and only then use `Popen()` directly.

Writing a convenience function that works in your case as you did is a good idea in general (though your particular example is less useful). `Popen()` can do many things and a convenience function that limits its power makes the code easier to maintain.

Don't call `p.communicate()` unless you need pass input, get output from the subprocess. Don't use `shell=True` unless you have *complete* control over the `command` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`call` is a convenience function for a typical use case of `Popen`. It's simpler to use it instead of the `Popen` constructor in this case because you are not using output from the executed command.

If there is a need to exchange some data with the running child process or for further processing of the command output (stdout, stderr) `Popen` and `communicate` would be a better fit.

If you're interested in the success of the call, there is another convenience function `check_call` which will raise an exception if the executed process exits with a non-zero status.